Seeking Explanation on Maven Artefact String Structure - Could Not Resolve Dependency
Maven uses various artifact strings with various commands / plugins.
For example with mvn dependency:tree it gives out strings like 'org.graalvm.regex:regex:jar:22.3.5:runtime' which can be interpreted as Group:Aartifact:type:Version:scope
For dependency not found, i am a bit confused. It gives strings like 'com.arcadedb:arcadedb-server:jar:tests:24.8.1-SNAPSHOT' it possibly can be interpreted as Group:Artifact:type:[what is this part??]:Version
It would be very helpful to me if someone with knowledge could explain the above and also other string structures. I could not find a consolidated documentation for the artifact strings used by Maven at various stages.

The general structure is:
groupId:artifactId:packaging:classifier:version:scope
Often packaging, classifier and/or scope are missing.
